# Dagger2 injection into child object

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

Not sure the title is clear but what I actually have is :

module :

```
@Module
public class TestUserModule {

    User user;

    public TestUserModule(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public User providesUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Component :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {TestUserModule.class})
public interface UserComponent {

    void inject(MyActivity activity);
    void inject(MyActivity2 activity);
}
```

in my App I create the component like this :

```
userComponent = DaggerUserComponent.builder().testUserModule(new TestUserModule(user)).build();
```

So, in my activity everything is ok, I can use `@Inject User user;` it works fine.

Now in my Activity, if I create an Object Foo, which look like this :

```
public class Foo {

@Inject
User user;

MyActivity activity;

public Foo(MyActivity activity){
this.activity = activity;
}
}
```

By instantiating Foo in my activity with `new Foo()`, I know my user will not be injected.

So my question is, what I have to update in my code to be able to inject Foo object in my activity (I think this is the way to do if I want to inject User in Foo but tell me if I'm wrong) ?

Also, where is a good place to build my component ? Everything in the App ??

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 choices:

**1. Use:**

```
@Inject
Foo mFoo;
```

Use this approach if lifecycle of foo is exactly the same as lifecycle of your activity.

**2. Use `Lazy`:**

```
@Inject
Lazy<Foo> mLazyFoo;
```

and then when you need the instance of `Foo`:

```
Foo myFoo = mLazyFoo.get();
```

Use this approach if you will need just one Foo for the entire lifecycle of the activity.

**3. Use `Provider`**

```
@Inject
Provider<Foo> mFooProvider;
```

and when you need instance an instance of `Foo`

```
Foo myFooFirstInstance = mFooProvider.get();
```

Use this approach when you will need more than one instance of `Foo` in your activity.

**4. Inject your foo manually (not recommended):**

In your `UserComponent` declare `void inject(Foo foo)` and then in your method:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo(...);
userComponent.inject(myFoo);
```

> Also, where is a good place to build my component ? Everything in the
>   App ??

For android app: yes, usually the component is built there.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but what if, in Foo constructor I want to get my activity from which I inject Foo ? Can I do that ?
With something like     @Inject public Foo(MyActivity activity){}

Comment: This sounds like circular dependency which is probably not a very good idea. Why not just define method `attach(Activity act)` and call it after instantiating a `Foo`?

Comment: Yes, it was just to know if there is a way to avoid attach(Activity), but I will do it in that way, thank's